# Custom style for ionic 2 loader spinner not working

Tags: ionic2

I am using the ionic 2 Loading widget to show a spinner but the custom style is not having any affect. The code for showing the Loading widget is:

```js
    let loading = Loading.create({
      content: `
      <div class="custom-spinner-container">
        <div class="custom-spinner-box"></div>
      </div>`,
      cssClass: 'myStyleSpinner'
    });

    this.nav.present(loading);
```

I have tried styling it as follows:

```html
.myStyleSpinner {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  font-size:128px;
  stroke: red;
  fill: red;
  margin-left:100px;
}
```

I have also tried applying the same style to the `custom-spinner-container` and the `custom-spinner-box` and to `ion-spinner svg` but still no joy.

I am using ionic Beta 6.

Comment: Any solution for this?